# Can't figure out whether MySQL or PHP badly encodes UTF8 strings

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have a form on a **PHP** page which inserts data into a **MySQL database**.
Some input fields may contain UTF8 characters as `é`, `è`, `â`, etc. When they are actually inserted into the database, everything gets messed up. For example, a column shows `QrÃ©on` instead of `Qréon`.

I used `setLocale(LC_CTYPE, 'FR_fr.UTF-8');` at the top of my page for PHP and this `<meta charset="utf-8">` is in my HTML header.
My database is run by **MySQL**, the storage engine is **InnoDB**, and the collation is `utf8_general_mysql500_ci`. I also tried `utf8_general_ci` and `utf8_bin` but I had no luck.

How do I know if this comes either from PHP or MySQL processing, and how can I fix it ?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can help you:

If your using mysql

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

If your using PDO use this:

```
$dbh->exec("set names utf8");
```

Otherwise i could be one of these which helps you specific:

```
//At the Top of you files
ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

//Before your queries
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8 ");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

Comment: `$db->exec("set names utf8");` worked like a charm. Thanks mate !

Comment: @qreon your welcome! Have a nice day. BTW: mysql drivers how don't provied  explicit mechanismus to use charset, you can use `SET NAMES`

Comment: @qreon Would be good if you accept and upvote the answer how helped you so people with the same problem find the answer faster!